# Looped sed statement - weird output

Tags: text-processing, sed, files

I wrote a small script that will recursively go through all *.py files within a directory and replace specific entries in the files.

So the files and their current content:

```
find . -name "*.py" -exec ls "{}" \; -exec cat "{}" \;
```

and that returns this:

```
./1/File1.py
import sys

./2/3/File3.py
import sys
sys.exit(1)

./6/7/File7.py
import sys
sys.exit()

./File0.py
import sys
```

Now the script I wrote is this:

```
for file in $(find . -name "*.py")
do
    echo "$file"
    sed 's/sys.exit.*/os_.exit()/g;s/import sys/&\nimport os/g' "$file"
done
```

Now if I ran those sed commands on their own, I would get my desired output. If I run them both together within my script, or like so:

```
find . -name "*.py" -exec sed 's/sys.exit.*/os_.exit()/g' "{}" \; -exec sed 's/import sys/&\nimport os/g' "{}" \;
```

it would end up duplicating my output like this:

```
./1/File1.py
import sys
import sys
import os

./2/3/File3.py
import sys
os_.exit()
import sys
import os
sys.exit(1)

./6/7/File7.py
import sys
os_.exit()
import sys
import os
sys.exit()

./File0.py
import sys
import sys
import os
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:** thanks to the link posted by don_crissti, I have edited the script to actually execute a 'one-liner'. I have posted this below, thanks to the input from all who commented it has resolved my issue.

```
find . -name "*.py" -exec ls "{}" \; -exec sed 's/sys.exit.*/os_.exit()/g;s/import sys/&\nimport os/g' "{}" \;
```

Comment: Why don't you put both edit commands in the same `sed` invocation?

Comment: I agree with @AlexP. I think that will also solve the original problem.

Comment: Good plan, will edit.

Comment: [Don't loop over find's output.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/22142). Other than that your script behaves as expected (that is, `sed` _autoprints_ all lines, even if no changes were made)

Comment: I noticed that as I hit save. Have fixed it now, thanks. Adding them into the one `sed` invocation has corrected my issue.
How would you recommend a loop over all *.py files to perform these edits in that case?

Comment: Note that you don't actually edit *the files*. The `sed` commands as written read a file and output the edited text. If you want to edit the files you need `sed -i`.

Comment: Sorry @AlexP, I meant to add that my script was to test the output before I actually edit them. I will add `-i` when I am confident it will output correctly.

Comment: @AlexP Since you are the first to propose joining of multiple `sed`'s in one, you should post the official answer.

Comment: @Iskustvo: OK done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is as should be expected, because each of the two `sed` commands operates *on the same unmodified input text*. In order to obtain the output which the inquirer expected, the two `s`ubstitute commands should be combined in one invocation of `sed`:

... `-exec sed -e 's/sys.exit.*/os_.exit()/g' -e 's/import sys/&\nimport os/g' "{}" \;`

or

... `-exec sed 's/sys.exit.*/os_.exit()/g;s/import sys/&\nimport os/g' "{}" \;`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and fix! Much appreciated.